# how to use ansible to get line by line from a url depending on the conditional value of a particular field in that line

Tags: ansible

ip-address  cpu ram .. if these are the dfiferent fields and i have multiple lines, how to get only those lines for which the cpu field value is greater than 75.

Using the lookup module i can get the lines one by one but how to apply the condition for the fields.

```
- debug: msg="{{item}}"
  when: item > 30
  with_items: "{{ lookup('url', 'http://{{ inventory_hostname }}:9200/_cat/nodes?h=ram.percent', wantlist=True) }}"
```

Here all the values are getting printed. The condition is not being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your test is whether `item` is numerically greater than 30, but `item` is a string.

You'd want at the very least to *attempt* to coerce item into an `int`:

```
debug: var=item
when: '(item|int) > 30'
with_items: # etc etc
```